# Line feed in output buffer after dispatch

Tags: php, zend-framework

Using the Zend Framework, I wanted to send a file.
But when doing so from my controller I noticed a LineFeed allready sent:

The following code:

```
$data = 'Let me test this';
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="output.txt";' );
//header('Content-Length: '.strlen($data));
ob_clean(); flush();
die($data);
```

Will give me the output.txt file:

```
[LF]
Let me test this
```

I have a preDispatch plugin, but I tried with the test code before exiting it, and the LF wasn't outputted yet. And all controller-files starts with `<?php`. without any LF first.

So, my question is:

- What happens between preDispatch plugins are run and the controller is dispatched?
  .. or even better: How can I find out where the LineFeed is outputted?

Comment: What is the output buffering/`flush()` call doing there at all? You don't seem to be doing anything that requires this... and following on from that, do you still get the extra linebreak if you comment out that line?

Comment: The `flush()` was just to make sure I had nothing in the buffer. But yes, even with the flush I get the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested your code with an empty `preDispatch()` method in a `Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract` derived plugin, and I don't get any LF in the output. I do get it, however, if I add `echo "\n"` explicitly into the `preDispatch()` method body.

So, chances are that your plugin is outputting the LF somewhere else. Maybe you are using a closing tag in your plugin? (just to discard possibilities).

> For files that contain only PHP code, the closing tag ("?>") is never
>   permitted. It is not required by PHP, and omitting it´ prevents the
>   accidental injection of trailing white space into the response.

(in the [Zend Framework Coding Standard](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html))

Comment: A VERY valid reply. And I actually noticed that my plugin DID have a closing `?>` tag. Happily I removed it, but the [LF] didn't go away *sob*

Comment: But still, I find your answer so plausible, that I will mark it as the correct one. I will go through all my files, removing any trailing `?>` tag!

Comment: Problem found with your help. One file contained `?>[LF]`

Comment: Good, I'm glad you could find it. These problems are really annoying to detect :)

Comment: For me, an empty line before php open tag ...